# Unable to pass variable to the mailable from component controller - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm getting an error when trying to create an invitation, and sending the link, to the user through mailable. I am successfully able to send mails, on successful creation of invite. But when I am trying to pass the variable `$invitation` to the `App\Mail\InvitationCreated` I am getting an error, even after initializing the variable in the mailable e.g. `__construct(Invitation $invitation)`.

Please help me to understand the issue here.

**App\Models\Invitation**

```
class Invitation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'invitation_token', 'registered_at',
    ];

    public function generateInvitationToken() {
        $this->invitation_token = substr(md5(rand(0, 9) . $this->email . time()), 0, 32);
    }

    public function getLink() {
        return urldecode(route('register') . '?invitation_token=' . $this->invitation_token);
    }
}
```

**App\Http\Livewire\InvitationController**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use App\Models\Invitation;
use App\Mail\InvitationCreated;

class InvitationController extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $showEditModal = false;
    public Invitation $invitation;

    protected $rules = [
        'invitation.email' => 'required | email | max:255 | unique:users,email',
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->invitation = new Invitation();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->invitation->generateInvitationToken();
        $invitation = $this->invitation->save();
        $this->showEditModal = false;

        Mail::to($this->invitation->email)->send(new InvitationCreated($invitation));
    }
}
```

**App\Http\Mail\InvitationCreated**

```
use App\Models\Invitation;

class InvitationCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(Invitation $invitation)
    {
        $this->invitation = $invitation;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('server@localhost.com')->view('emails.invite-created');
    }
}
```

**resources\views\emails\invite-created**

```
<p>Hi,</p>
<p>Someone has invited you to access their account.</p>
 
<a href="{{ $invitation->getLink() }}">Click here</a> to activate!
```

**Error Which I'm Getting**

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\InvitationCreated::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Invitation, bool given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\2020\app\Http\Livewire\Backend\UserManagement\InvitationController.php on line 54
```

Comment: your error is self explain `must be an instance of App\Models\Invitation, bool given,` please check this and fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```php
Mail::to($this->invitation->email)->send(new InvitationCreated($this->invitation));
```

`$invitation` to `$this->invitation`

as it `$invitation = $this->invitation->save();` this code return  true or false data is save or not

so you can get `instance of App\Models\Invitation` from public property `$this->invitation`

---

inorder to send data to mail view you need to create public proprty

```php
use App\Models\Invitation;

class InvitationCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $invitation;

    public function __construct(Invitation $invitation)
    {
        $this->invitation = $invitation;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('server@localhost.com')->view('emails.invite-created');
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I get it, I followed it as per your said instructions, but now its throwing a new error, `Undefined variable: invitation (View: resources\views\emails\invite-created.blade.php)`. Its throwing this error even after defining it in construct method.

Comment: in mailable `public $invitation` is missing please check

Comment: Opps! Thanks alot for your time, its working perfectly.

Comment: @ToxifiedHashkey your welcome please mark this as answer